# How to compare boolean values between tables for update in a clean way

Tags: postgresql, boolean, postgresql-10

In this fiddle: https://rextester.com/edit/SPVQGW21946

I would like to update `tableA` with `tableB` -- the value on the first row, field `ccc` from `null` to `false`

[image]

Here's an `upsert` query that needs a way to compare if `tableB` has different values, then update those fields in a simple way.

I'm stuck at the `where` clause, I'm not sure how to compare `boolean` fields to `update`:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (company, option, new, gap, ccc) 
   SELECT company, option, new, gap, ccc
   FROM   tableB
 ON CONFLICT (company, option) 
 DO update
   set new= EXCLUDED.new,
   gap = excluded.gap,
   ccc = excluded.ccc

 WHERE 
      ?
```

Is there a clean way to compare boolean values to update?

(The reason I have `insert` is because `tableB` may have new rows.)

Comment: Why are you using `INSERT` if you want to update?

Comment: `tableB` may have new rows, I should have that in there.

Comment: `WHERE tablea.ccc is distinct from excluded.ccc;` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `IS DISTINCT FROM` in the where clause.

```
 WHERE (tableA.new,tableA.gap,tableA.ccc) 
IS DISTINCT FROM (EXCLUDED.new,excluded.gap,excluded.ccc);
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4dcc97296a01363afbd314d9b6ee6800)

Comment: Thanks that works, why did I think I couldn't use distinct from.. I had it but postgres threw an error.